# SQLite3::SQLException: in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Migration:

```
class AddUserIdToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :photos, :user_id, :integer
    execute 'update photos inner join albums on albums.id = photos.album_id set photos.user_id = albums.user_id'
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :photos, :user_id
  end
end
```

rake db:migrate, display error:

> -- add_column(:photos, :user_id, :integer)    -> 0.0010s
>   -- execute("update photos inner join albums on albums.id = photos.album_id set photos.user_id = albums.user_id") rake aborted!
>   StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations
>   canceled:
>
> SQLite3::SQLException: near "inner": syntax error: update photos inner
>   join albums on albums.id = photos.album_id set photos.user_id =
>   albums.user_id/home/borowskiy/projects/galaxy/bdsmgalaxy/db/migrate/20110731191428_add_user_id_to_photos.rb:4:in
>   `up'

with trace:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "inner": syntax error: update photos inner join albums on albums.id = photos.album_id set photos.user_id = albums.user_id/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:278:in `block in execute'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.7/lib/patches/db/activerecord.rb:17:in `log_with_miniprofiler'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:278:in `execute'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:281:in `measure'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:334:in `method_missing'
/home/borowskiy/projects/galaxy/bdsmgalaxy/db/migrate/20110731191428_add_user_id_to_photos.rb:4:in `up'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `up'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:281:in `measure'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:410:in `block in migrate'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.22/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/borowskiy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

You SQL query is wrong. The correct sql update query should be like this

```
update photos set photos.user_id = albums.user_id from albums where albums.id = photos.album_id
```

Please change your migration file to this

```
class AddUserIdToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :photos, :user_id, :integer
    execute "update photos set photos.user_id = albums.user_id from albums where albums.id = photos.album_id"
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :photos, :user_id
  end
end
```

and run it again.